# How to create auto-input script based on agularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I´m trying to implement a greaskemonkey script to make an auto-input, but I cannot find a way to do it.

What I have:
HTML form:

```
<form ng-submit="buy(quantity2)">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" ng-model="my.quantity" style="width:30px" maxlength="2">
    </form>
```

I simply don´t know how to input a value for the box, usually I would do

```
$("input[name='quantity']:first").val("1");
```

Unfortunately *val* doesn´t exists here. Need a help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your better understand i just give you a example how you can take your value.

HTML form:

```
 <form ng-submit="buy(youravlue)">
      <input name="quantity" id="quantity" type="text" ng-model="youravlue" style="width:30px" maxlength="2">
</form>
```

using ng-submit you can take your value this way.

```
 $scope.buy=function(data){
    console.log(data);
 }
```

using ID you can take your value this way.

```
angular.element("#quantity").val();
```

Comment: The problem is: The HTML part is already done, I can´t change it, there´s no id. The script needs to auto-fill inputs, but I´m having trouble finding a way to implement this in a input with no ID.

Edit: Thanks for your edit!

Comment: Ok fine, i have added another solution. you can pass your input object using buy function and take the value after submit.

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs we have to find the element either by id or querySelector or querySelectorAll and wrap it over angular.element which will provide jqlite(lighter version of jquery)

Refer this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("input[name='quantity']")).val("1");
```

Comment: But for that especific part didn´t worked. The value still not appear in the inputbox for some reason. Where do you think the problem is? The idea is simple, I don´t see where a problem can happen

Besides that, thanks for your link, it helped with another part of the script.